# Subdomain not working

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain

I created a Subdomain for one of my domains. After creation in Apache & entry in DNS the Subdomain isn't pointing to it specified directory instead it points to its Main Domain's Directory

**Main Domain**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com *.domain.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/

<Directory /var/www/domain/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.error.log

#Possible Values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
#alert, emerg.
LogLevel alert

ServerSignature On
```

**Subdomain**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName orders.domain.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/cpanel/

<Directory /var/www/domain/cpanel/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.error.log

#Possible Values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
#alert, emerg.
LogLevel alert

ServerSignature On
```

After creation of the entry in "/etc/apache2/sites-available" & Virtual Link in "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled", I restarted Apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a wildcard ServerAlias in your main entry that you will have to adjust or remove:

```
ServerAlias domain.com *.domain.com
```

That's going to catch everything, including orders.domain.com.  It's also possible that moving your entry for orders.domain.com to be earlier in your config will fix the problem.

Comment: +1, I would just add that having it earlier means having it before in alphabetic order of site-enabled/<name of site>, this is why numbers are usually used has prefix for these file names.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me solved the same issue. I realized that I was using a wild card in my apache configuration and once I changed that It still didn't quite work right. I realized I had also used a wildcard in my dns entries for aliasing. Once I changed the dns records for my main domain by removing the wild card and then added an primary domain record for my sub domain it all worked.
So.. I had in my apache config...
ServerAlias *.domain.com  that I changed to ServerAlias www.domain.com
and then the same for the alias in the domain records. That fixed the issue.